# GWT - no urls in development mode tab

Tags: debugging, gwt, configuration

What could be the reason for not showing any urls to html files while debugging the GWT project? The tab is empty, it is not possible to debug any of the pages that are stored in 'war' directory.

[image]

I guess it is all about the configuration. Thank you for any hints on how to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is lack of web app nature. Add to *.project* file the following line:

```
<natures>
    ...
    <nature>com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.webAppNature</nature>
    ...
</natures>
```